# Moving apache environment from HP-UX to RedHat w/ruby

Tags: apache, redhat, hp-ux

I have been tasked with moving someone else's site and work from HP-UX to RedHat since our HP-UX system is going away.  I have all the components on the RedHat server in place (apache, MySQL, Ruby, passenger) that were on the HP-UX system.  I have apache UP on the Redhat system.  I have exported the MySQL DB from HP-UX to the RedHat.  I have copied all the directories that hold the app from one server to another.

My issue is trying to NOT get the Welcome to Apache screen on my redhat server but my app.  I have the site listed in the site-enabled.  I have the Include on the httpd.conf file to include all the sites.  I have even tried **Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/*** as well as **Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/**.  No difference.

I am not sure where else to go to look from old, old HP-UX Apache to the new, just installed RedHat system.

HP-UX 11.31 running Apache 2.2.9
RedHat 7.1 running Apache 2.4.6

What else do you need to know?  Where else do I need to look?
Thanks!
Vince

Comment: Found something in the error log: "[Thu Apr 07 15:34:59.519519 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 30821] [client 10.128.128.161:52262] AH01630: client denied by server conf
iguration: /var/rails/tip/public/"

Comment: OK... so I added this

<Directory "/var/rails/tip/public">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

but get a new error:

[Thu Apr 07 15:42:05.358327 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 30930] [client 10.128.128.161:52372] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/r
ails/tip/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Seems I am missing something in the way the previous admin got the site to come up.

Comment: Also, if someone can show me how to add line spaces in the comments my information that I add would not be a run on sentence.  The example in the help doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't post comment... have you tried to add

```
Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/*.conf
```

in the httpd.conf?

note the .conf at the end

Comment: yes, and I have.  The names there were without so I copied them to <name>.conf.  Even stopped and restarted the httpd vs just a reload.

Comment: Have you set SELinux permissions on the new server on app folders? I know this link is CentOS, but that is a ripoff of rhel https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: Yes, the rights and ownership are the same as the default html files.

Comment: what is the output of httpd -S ? are your <name>.conf files listed?

Comment: I can't dump all the output of the httpd -S but here is what I think you are looking for: port 8080 namevhost localhost (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/all.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/tip.conf:1)
port 1080 namevhost localhost (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/tipfiles.conf:1)

Comment: [root@s928-apsaptip ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a lot more required under the hood.  One can not just move an older ruby/rails app to a new version.  So instead of fighting this battle due to a versioning issue I am just going to close it out for now.

Thanks for all help.